# Adjusting Brick Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

This is my node setup:
[image]
And this is it's output:
[image]

As you can see, the mortar-depth between the bricks is even, however, I only want the red-colored portion to have mortar-depth and the rest to be flat. Is there any way to do so without using external textures?

Comment: Use the same value you use to control the mix shader to control the displacement.

Comment: @Ezra ok, that worked, but another problem just popped up, for any surface parallel to the Z-Axis the texture's getting stretched out and way to rectify that?

Comment: You need to uv unwrap it, or make better use of coordinates.